# Variable if para una pàgina Wordpress concreta

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola a todos (otra vez),
os explico, tengo esta funciòn para wordpress

```html
<?php
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
 return '[..] <a class="more" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Siga leyendo &raquo;</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
?>
```

Y ahora tengo creada una web igual pero en ingles (Startpage) y necesito la funciòn if que le diga que cuando esta este activa en vez de poner Siga leyendo, ponga "Read More", pero no se muy bien como desarrrollarla.
Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: En qué variable recoges el idioma?

Comment: El tema es que la web no es hecha por mi y el que la hizo creo un archivo llamado fornt-page.php y un custom template llamado fron-page_engl.php, por lo tanto, son dos web iguales, pero en diferente idioma y linkeadas a un botòn con las tipicas banderas. Por lo tanto necesito que la variable referencie la pàgina en ingles y el single en ingles.....y eso es lo que me esta matando.

Comment: ¿puedes mostrar un var_dump() de $_REQUEST y de $_SESSION? ¿tienes algun distintivo para el idioma en la URL?

Comment: La web esta online y no le puedo meter un var_dump(), pero el link esta aqui www.curator.biz. La web esta en Alemàn, pero puedes ver las banderas en la esquina superioe derecha.

Comment: Pero ¿las dos páginas están en la misma instalación de WordPress o en instalaciones separadas?

Comment: En la misma instalaciòn, en la carpeta themes.

Comment: perdona si no te puedo contestar a todo al 100%, pero llevo bastante poco trabajando con php y con wordpress.....

Comment: Creo que debes dar algunos detalles más en la pregunta, para ayudar en la solución del problema, para ello la puedes editar diciendo que ambas páginas están en la misma instalación de WP. Deberías indicar si usan la misma URL y como haces para diferenciar el lenguaje, si usas algún plugin , si es una sola página, si todas las páginas de un lenguaje tienen un elemento en común que las de otro lenguaje no tienen, por ejemplo un nombre de categoría.